# Does Array.prototype.indexOf() work different in React.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, indexof

Im trying to understand how this code works I am using Array.prototype.indexOf() to to get the index of the state array so it can be updated. I am told to pass an object in the parameters of indexOf() but i thought that no two objects are equal so how can indexOf() return the right index am i missing something here?
here is my code

```
 handleIncrement(counter){//passing object here from child component

         const counters = [...this.state.counters];//cloning
         const index = counters.indexOf(counter)//geting index of param counter 
         console.log(counter === index)//how did index return true if this returns false???
        counters[index] = {...counter};// spread object onto index pos

        counters[index].value++;//increment value
        this.setState({counters})//updates state just fine no errors
     }
```

Comment: Is this a feature of react.js ?

Comment: `indexOf` works exactly as in every other JavaScritp env. What's the content of `counters`?

Comment: It is a feature of JavaScript.

Comment: counters[index] = counter, that doesn't mean index = counter

Comment: You're misinterpreting `indexOf`. `indexOf` returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present. So `index` is just the index of the `counter` in `counters`. You're comparing an object (`counter`) to a number (`index`). Regardless, as you pointed out this setup won't work for finding an object.

Comment: counters has an array of objects `counters: [{id: 1, value: 0 }, {id: 2, value: 0 }, etc]`

Comment: the correct test is `counters[index] === counter` not `index === counter`

Comment: @BrettDeWoody true i did not realize that i see what you mean

Comment: @BrettDeWoody well if the object passed to `handleIncrement` is a reference to the one in the `counters` then it will work fine for finding the index. You just need to be sure that is what you want to be doing :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're misinterpreting `.indexOf()`. `indexOf` returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or `-1` if it is not present. So `index` would be the index of the `counter` in `counters`. In short, you're comparing an object (`counter`) to a number (`index`).

That said, it also depends on how you're searching for the object in the array. If trying to find an object which matches a certain key/value structure, `.indexOf` won't work for the reason you mentioned. As pointed out by Gabriele, if searching using a reference, it will work.

If using a reference isn't an option, as an alternative you could use [`.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex), or `.map()`, and find the object based on one of its properties, like `id`.

```js
const counters = [{id: 1, value: 0}, {id: 2, value: 0}, {id: 3, value: 0}, {id: 4, value: 0}];

const findBySameness = {id: 3, value: 0};
const findByRef = counters[2];

const indexBySameness = counters.indexOf(findBySameness);
console.log('Index by sameness: ', indexBySameness); // Do not find the object index
const indexByRef = counters.indexOf(findByRef);
console.log('Index by reference: ', indexByRef); // Found the object index

// If a reference to the object is not available you can use the following methods

// With .findIndex
const index3 = counters.findIndex(item => item.id === findBySameness.id)
console.log('Index: ', index3); // Found the object index

// With .map
const index2 = counters.map(item => item.id).indexOf(findBySameness.id);
console.log('Index: ', index2); // Found the object index
```